# Manage labels/options existing attribute not working

Tags: attributes, custom, custom-attributes

When I add new labels to my existing attribute, it looks fine in the catalog-->attributes tab.

When I try to add these new options to a configurable product that allready has this attribute set in it it won't work.

I try to add the new attribute label/option, by following the quick add option. After that I see the product in the list, but also 2 'false' products. (see screenshot). The problem is that were it says 'broodje' the new products don't have a value for 'broodje' and I don't know why not. You see that for example italiaanse bol and speltbroodje don't have a value on the right side, and all the others do.[image] I've looked everywhere, but a few months ago adding a value wasn't this hard.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

well it simply is becouse you can't. It is a configurable product is my guess. You can think of it as selecting colors for clothes. There's simply one option to choose red. At you configuration theres just one option duits broodje, you can't pick 2. As for spelt broodje, there is no option defined. You should go to speltbroodje individually and select an option for broodje.

I'm dutch so i know what your trying to do. You have something like a product called broodje and you want the user to select what kind of broodje. You should make an attribute called soort broodje (kind of sandwich - for the english people here) and this can have like: spelt, volkoren, tarwe. The way you should go depends on what kind of products with what kind of options you want to sell. You can only choose 1 option for broodje. And when theres no option for broodje as in speltbroodje you cant select it becouse its not there. post some more info about your products and options and how you want to show it to your customer so i can give you some advice on that. I have a bakery webshop myself.

watch this video for more info about how you should create configurable products. If you want another type of product theres videos for it in the same channel. This wel help you solve your problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyy2NmjckhA

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply!

It is indeed a configurable product, as you can see here: http://www.debakgigant.nl/beleg-je-eigen-broodje/broodje-zalm.html you see what i'm trying to say. This is one of the configurable sandwiches I have. But I want to add some breads to chose from like for example the spelt sandwich.

But it's not working the way it did before, I created the attribute 'Selecteer broodje' in there are the options defined. I've put the new options over there but when trying to add them to the products it won't do it. At first it's there, after saving it isn't.